# Is it possible to publish multiple android libraries to the same package on github using the maven-plugin? then import the libraries together or alone

Tags: android, maven, github, android-gradle-plugin, maven-plugin

I'm trying to publish multiple libraries to github from the same project in android using the maven-publish plugin. I'm trying to make it so that a person can either consume the whole project with all the libraries eg import com.example.libraries; or import it as single modules such as import com.example.libraries.lib1, import com.example.libraries.lib2 and so on. However, I am unable to do so. Is this possible using Github and if so, how can one go about it?

```
  //build.gradle for lib1
       publications {
            maven(MavenPublication) {

                groupId "com.github.example.libraries"
                artifactId "lib1"
                version System.getProperty("version")

                artifact "/build/outputs/aar/lib1-release.aar"
}

  //build.gradle for lib2
       publications {
            maven(MavenPublication) {

                groupId "com.github.example.libraries"
                artifactId "lib2"
                version System.getProperty("version")

                artifact "/build/outputs/aar/lib2-release.aar"
}
```

Comment: Got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution for a similar problem using flavors.

However, if you have lib1 and lib2 in different modules your solution should work by using the maven-publish plugin in each build.gradle file.

First, declare as many flavors as you need:

```
flavorDimensions "libs"
productFlavors {
    lib1 {
        dimension "libs"
    }
    lib2 {
        dimension "libs"
    }
}
```

Then you can use sourceSets to specify the sources for your flavors:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
        res {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        }
    }
    lib1 {
        java {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/lib1/java']
        }
    }
    lib2 {
        java {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/lib2/java']
        }
    }
}
```

At the end, you can publish both libraries using maven-publish plugin:

```
publishing {
publications {
    lib1(MavenPublication) {
            groupId "com.github.example.libraries"
            artifactId "lib2"
            version System.getProperty("version")
            artifact("/build/outputs/aar/lib2-release.aar") {
            extension 'aar'
        }
    }
    lib2(MavenPublication) {
            groupId "com.github.example.libraries"
            artifactId "lib2"
            version System.getProperty("version")
            artifact("/build/outputs/aar/lib2-release.aar") {
            extension 'aar'
        }
    }
  }
}
```